# Spring MVC displaying arraylist in JSP correctly

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, arraylist

i have a problem whith the displaying of an arraylist in jsp. it displays everything in one line for each person making repetition .
i have a table with columns (phone number,fax,phone2,email)

here is my dao function:

```
@Override
    public ArrayList<String> moyenCom(Authentication auth) {
        String login=auth.getName();
        List list;
        List listres = null;
        ArrayList<String> array1=new ArrayList<String>();

        //ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        SessionFactory factory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        //Your operation

        String sql1="select r.id_responsable from WEBCARE.PERSONNE p,WEBCARE.RESPONSABLE r,WBB_CLU.ABONNE_COMPTE ac,WBB_CLU.COMPTE_CLU c where p.id=r.id_responsable and r.id_abonne=ac.id_abonne and c.id_compte=ac.id_compte and c.login=:x";
        SQLQuery query1 = session.createSQLQuery(sql1);
        query1.setParameter("x",login);
        query1.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        list=query1.list();

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

        String res =list.get(i).toString();



      String[] parts = res.split("=");
      String part2 = parts[1];



        System.out.println("id du responsable est"+res);
        System.out.println("id du responsable spliteeee est "+part2);



        session.beginTransaction();
        String sql="select mc.information from WEBCARE.MOYEN_COMMUNICATION mc,WEBCARE.PERSONNE p where p.id=mc.id_categorie and mc.id_categorie=:part2 and mc.categorie=1";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);

        query.setParameter("part2",part2);

        query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        listres=query.list();

         for(int i1=0;i1<listres.size();i1++){

            String resu =listres.get(i1).toString();
            System.out.println("info "+resu);
            array1.add(resu);

    }



        }

  System.out.println(array1);

    return array1;

    }
```

my controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/fichets")
public String fichets(Model model,Authentication auth){

    Authentication authen = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      String name = authen.getName(); //get logged in username


model.addAttribute("moycoms",metier.moyenCom(auth));



return "InfoAbonneTS";
}
```

and my jsp page :

```
  <c:forEach items="${resps}" var="resp">

      <tr>


      <td  id="date">${resp.nom} ${resp.prenom}</td>
      <td>${resp.poste}</td>
      <td>${resp.password}</td>

     <c:forEach items="${moycoms}" var="moycom">
       <td>${moycom}</td>
      </c:forEach> 

      </tr>
    </tbody>

    </c:forEach>
```

The function returns the field information witch contains all the 4 informations that should be displayed each in every column.
arraylist returned is :

```
{information=01234567890}, {information=01999999999}, {information=0199999333}, {information=resp1@gmail.com}, {information=00 }, {information=0622355114}, {information=0588888888}, {information=respons3@gmail.com}, {information=00 }, {information=0111111111}, {information=0666666666}, {information=responsable4@gmail.com}
```

so the first four information should be displayed each in every column ,the second four same thing...in this example i have 3 persons.
i can't display this correctly any help?

[resps is for displaying the first 3 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWe8l.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the data it looks like a List of Map. Try this code

```
<c:forEach items="${moycoms}" var="moycom" varStatus="stat">
                <c:if test="${stat.index%4==0 && stat.index!=0}">
                    <tr>
                </c:if>
                    <td>${moycom['information']}</td>
                <c:if test="${stat.index%4==0 && stat.index!=0}">
                    </tr>
                </c:if>
         </c:forEach>
```

stat variable is used to find the current index. We are adding the `<tr>` based on the index so that its done for every fourth index. If resp contains some identifier which could be used for finding the correct user then use `<c:if>` for matching. Please provide additional information

Comment: thanks @Anand Muley for your reply, yes resp contains id used to display the four columns however i don't get how can i use it in jsp to verify the displaying of the array list , i tried the code with stat its not working.. i have just to separate the values of the arraylist by group of 4 to display each in a line.

Comment: Checked the code you are converting the query results in string here :

            `String resu =listres.get(i1).toString();
            System.out.println("info "+resu);
            array1.add(resu);`

Change it to :


            `Map resu = (Map)listres.get(i1);
            array1.add(resu);`

Comment: Yes i have deleted the line in query wish converts the result to map i don't need to convert it now .the problem is the displaying in jsp @Anand Muley

Comment: Please post the error if any. I think above code should do the trick of displaying the actual value corresponding to information. If displaying means clubbing the 4 values for each user and displaying in a row then its a business logic you will have to compare the id from resps and something matching with moycom to distinguish the user for a row. How is it displaying now ?

Answer (score 0):

> you are adding only "moycoms" attribute to the model object
>
> but you jstl starts from

```
<c:forEach items="${resps}" var="resp">
```

> you are not adding any "resps" param in  your model object